# ¿Como validar un campo vacion en vb.net aspx?

Tags: vb.net, vba, aspx

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Quiero validar si un campo es vacío, si el campo es vacío pues que envié un mensaje que ese campo es obligatorio y no continue el proceso hasta que los campos estén completados. He intentado validar pero me muestra el mensaje pero continua el proceso y se registra vacíos los campos y no deseo eso hasta que todos los campos estén completados.

btn_Grabar

```
Protected Sub btnGrabar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGrabar.Click

        Try
            Dim numDam As String = txtNumDam.Text.Trim()
            Dim regNumDam As String = txtRegNumDam.Text.Trim()
            Dim numBooking As String = txtNumBooking.Text.Trim()
            Dim lineaNaviera As String = txtHiddenCodLinea2.Text()
            Dim nomDespachador As String = txtNomDespachador.Text.Trim()
            Dim dni As String = txtDni.Text.Trim()
            Dim descMercancia As String = txtDescMercancia.Text.Trim()
            Dim celular As String = txtCelular.Text.Trim()
            Dim correo As String = txtCorreo.Text.Trim()
            Dim ruc As String = txtRuc.Text.Trim()
            Dim razonSocial As String = txtRazonSocial.Text.Trim()

            'Aquí estoy validando pero el problema es que sale el mensaje pero continua con el proceso de inserción'
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(numDam) Then
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Ingrese N° DAM')</script>")

            End If




            Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cadenadeConexion)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("sp_ins_solicitud_exportacion", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodSolExportacion", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters("@CodSolExportacion").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numDam", numDam)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regNumDam", regNumDam)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numBooking", numBooking)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineaNaviera", lineaNaviera)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomDespachador", nomDespachador)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dni", dni)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descMercancia", descMercancia)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", celular)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correo", correo)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruc", ruc)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@razonSocial", razonSocial)


            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim CodSolExportacion As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@CodSolExportacion").Value)

            If AdjuntoBooking.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoBooking.FileName, AdjuntoBooking.FileBytes, "Booking")
            End If

            If AdjuntoDAM.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoDAM.FileName, AdjuntoDAM.FileBytes, "DAM")
            End If

            If AdjuntoGuias.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoGuias.FileName, AdjuntoGuias.FileBytes, "Guias de Remision")
            End If

            If AdjuntoOpUsuales.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoOpUsuales.FileName, AdjuntoOpUsuales.FileBytes, "Operaciones Usuales")
            End If

            If AdjuntoPago.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoPago.FileName, AdjuntoPago.FileBytes, "Pago")
            End If

            If AdjuntoPagoAdic.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoPagoAdic.FileName, AdjuntoPagoAdic.FileBytes, "Pagos Adicionales")
            End If

            If AdjuntoCargaFactTer.HasFile Then
                insertarArchivo(CodSolExportacion, AdjuntoCargaFactTer.FileName, AdjuntoCargaFactTer.FileBytes, "Carta Facturacion a Terceros")
            End If

            Response.Write("<script>alert('Se registro correctamente')</script>")
            LimpiarCajas()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Me muestra el mensaje de la validación pero continua con el código siguiente hasta registrar a la base de datos. Deseo que no se registre hasta que todos los campos estén completados.

Comment: Saludos.  Después del `LimpiarCajas()` coloca un `End If` para el código que comparte corresponderá al del `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(numDam) Then`; ahora el `End if` que tienes debajo del `Response.Write("<script>alert('Ingrese N° DAM')</script>")` reemplazalo por  `Else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de la validación, debes incluir un Exit Sub. Esto permitirá salir de la rutina tras fallar la validación...

```
        'Aquí estoy validando pero el problema es que sale el mensaje pero continua con el proceso de inserción'
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(numDam) Then
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Ingrese N° DAM')</script>")
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Si no se forza la salida, la ejecución continúa aunque falle la validación...